# How to achieve Azure Queue for large size Images?

Tags: azure, message-queue, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-storage-queues

Problem:
We want to allow user to upload images and save them in azure blob. In case if azure blob is down then we will loose these image so we want to put a Queue between the Client and Blob.

Idea is that when user upload the image, it should go into Queue and then it should be picked up from the backend API to put into the Azure blob storage.

Azure Storage Queue and Service Bus has size limit of 64kb and 1mb only.

what other options I can use to achieve this ?

*Edited with more info.

Comment: Upload the image to blob storage, and send the URI to the image to the queue instead.

Comment: Should I expect blob to behave same as Queue though ? Basically if I am using Blob then do I need to use queue ?

Comment: You don't have enough information in your question about what it is you're doing, including what / how are things getting put on the queue, what process is receiving things off the queue, and what you are doing when processing the queue.  If you want to notify the process that an image is ready to be processed via a queue, then writing the image to be process to blob storage, and then sending a message on the queue with a pointer to where that file is, is all I am suggesting.  To clarify further, you are using both blob storage **and** the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put images on the Azure Blob Storage and create Azure Function with trigger on Blob Storage. This is intended way to do it, don't use queue what it wasn't intended for.

```
[FunctionName("BlobTriggerCSharp")]        
public static void Run(
     [BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}")] Stream myBlob, 
     string name, 
     ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger for \n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} bytes");
}
```

Comment: I just udpated my question with more info. I would like to have queue between client and azure blob. Is that wrong design ?

Comment: Honestly it is a bit, because there seems like no need for it. I checked your updated answer and you still didn't say why, you just said you want it in the middle.

In general blobs are for files, queues are for messages. Just stay like this and you will be fine. If you need queue for some reason put file on blob and file URL on message que.

Comment: Hey Adam, may be I am not clear on understanding of queue or not explaining this right. Aren't queues used as buffer mechanism ? So if Blob service was down and user uploads the image, then we can hold that image in the queue and when the blob service comes up it can read image from queue and insert into blob storage. Here blob service would be custom web api.

Comment: Hey. No problem, let me explain. They aren't buffer but can serve as one, but definitely not for service downtime scenarios. Although , mostly they are designed to hold short lived messages for event based processing architectures. Notice that both Queues and Blobs are part of one service so if one goes down most likely both will. In case of temporary downtime you should implement retry policy on your client. In C# there is polly library for this, but Storage SDK handles retry policy as built in feature.

Feel free to check my viedeo on this.
https://youtu.be/UzTtastcBsk

Comment: If this helped you, feel free to mark this topic as answered.